# Sum of particular column with month and year with fiscal year from custom date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in my table:

```
uniqueId    d_date      amount
1         2018-02-01    100.25
2         2019-03-01    456.5
3         2018-02-01    455
4         2019-05-01    200.48
5         2018-06-01    100
6         2019-07-01    200
7         2018-12-01    6950
8         2019-02-01    60
9         2020-01-20    100
```

Now when I enter `start date = '2018-03-12'` then my fiscal year must start with `march 2018 to feb 2019` and so on.

If i enter `start date = '2019-05-12' then my fiscal year must start with May 2019 to April 2020`

I have tried below query but it is not working properly and also it calculate past year which is 2017 I do not want any data from past year from my entered custom date. So if entered start date = '2018-03-12' then is must start calculation for 2018 and above years only. No past year.

```
Declare @startdate as date
Declare @monthDate as int
Declare @ownmonth as int
set @startdate = '2018-03-12'
set @monthDate = month(@startdate)
set @ownmonth = 1
select
    year(dateadd(month, -@monthDate, d_date)) year,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+1 > 12 then @ownmonth else @monthDate+1 End  then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+2 > 12 then @ownmonth+1 else @monthDate+2  End then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+3 > 12 then @ownmonth+2 else @monthDate+3  End  then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+4 > 12 then @ownmonth+3 else @monthDate+4  End  then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+5 > 12 then @ownmonth+4 else @monthDate+5  End  then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+6 > 12 then @ownmonth+5 else @monthDate+6  End  then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+7 > 12 then @ownmonth+6 else @monthDate+7  End  then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+8 > 12 then @ownmonth+7 else @monthDate+8  End then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+9 > 12 then @ownmonth+8 else @monthDate+9  End  then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+10 > 12 then @ownmonth+9 else @monthDate+10  End then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+11 > 12 then @ownmonth+10 else @monthDate+11  End then amount end) ,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = case when @monthDate+12 > 12 then @ownmonth+11 else @monthDate+12  End then amount end) ,
    sum(amount) total
from mytable
group by year(dateadd(month, -@monthDate, amount))
order by year
```

But above query does not show proper year & month wise data

Now I want output with fiscal year calculation:

```
Year    Mar     Apr    May    Jun   July   Aug   Sept   Oct   Nov    Dec  Jan     Feb    Total
2018     -      -       -     100     -     -    -     -     -      6950   -      60     7110
2019    456.5    -    200.48   -    200     -    -     -     -        -    100     -     956.98
```

I can not use `PIVOT` as it is not supported in my compact SQL Server version.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does your version support CTEs?

Comment: No it does not support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule for a fiscal year is the year's March until the following year's February:

```
date       | fiscal year
...        | ...
2018-02-28 | 2017
2018-03-01 | 2018
...        | 2018
2019-02-28 | 2018
2019-03-01 | 2019
...        | ...
```

That means when we subtract two months from a date, we get a date the year of which is the fiscal year:

```
date       | date - 2 months | fiscal year
...        | ...             | ...
2018-02-28 | 2017-12-28      | 2017
2018-03-01 | 2018-01-01      | 2018
...        | ...             | 2018
2019-02-28 | 2018-12-28      | 2018
2019-03-01 | 2019-01-01      | 2019
...        | ...             | ...
```

```
select
  year(dateadd(month, -2, d_date)) as fiscal_year,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  3 then amount else 0 end) as mar,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  4 then amount else 0 end) as apr,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  5 then amount else 0 end) as may,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  6 then amount else 0 end) as jun,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  7 then amount else 0 end) as jul,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  8 then amount else 0 end) as aug,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  9 then amount else 0 end) as sep,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = 10 then amount else 0 end) as oct,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = 11 then amount else 0 end) as nov,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = 12 then amount else 0 end) as dec,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  1 then amount else 0 end) as jan,
  sum(case when month(d_date) =  2 then amount else 0 end) as feb,
  sum(amount) as total
from mytable
group by year(dateadd(month, -2, d_date))
order by year(dateadd(month, -2, d_date));
```

If you want to limit this to the fiscal year a given date resides in, add:

```
where year(dateadd(month, -2, d_date)) = year(dateadd(month, -2, @given_date))
```

And well, if you want to limit this to the fiscal years beginning with that year, that would of course be:

```
where year(dateadd(month, -2, d_date)) >= year(dateadd(month, -2, @given_date))
```

**UPDATE:** You want a fiscal year to start with the first day of the month of a given date. I.e. If the given date is 1990-04-23, then a fiscal year starts with April. This changes above query only slightly, because rather than subtracting 2 months (for March), we must generalize this to subtracting one month less than the given month.

I am using a modulo operation when comparing months in order not to end up with months 13, 14, etc.

```
select
  year(dateadd(month, - month(@startdate) + 1, d_date)) as fiscal_year,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  0) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as first,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  1) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as second,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  2) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as third,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  3) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as fourth,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  4) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as fith,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  5) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as sixth,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  6) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as seventh,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  7) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as eighth,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  8) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as nineth,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) +  9) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as tenth,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) + 10) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as eleventh,
  sum(case when month(d_date) = (month(@startdate) + 11) % 12 then amount else 0 end) as twelfth,
  sum(amount) as total
from mytable
group by year(dateadd(month, - month(@startdate) + 1, d_date))
order by year(dateadd(month, - month(@startdate) + 1, d_date));
```

And again, if we want our results start from the fiscal year of the given date, we'd add:

```
where year(dateadd(month, - month(@startdate) + 1, d_date)) >= year(@startdate)
```

Comment: Yes but you have mentioned static month number & name in select query. 
I want to auto calculate based on the `@given_date` . If i change my `@given_date` to 2019-08-10 then your select won't be work as it was defined static month number.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean a fiscal year is not March to February, but can be anything, like August to July or June 16 to June 15? And the given date marks which day a fiscal year starts with? Please elaborate.

Comment: I mean fiscal year must be generated on the basis of `@give_date`. 
`For example :
1) If i have set @given_date = '2019-03-11' => Fiscal year must start from March to Feb.
2) If i have set @given_date = '2019-05-30' => Fiscal year must start form May to April
3) If i have set @given_date = '2019-07-25'  => Fiscal year must start from July to June.`

Comment: Okay, sorry. So I've misunderstood. After all, the logic stays exactly the same. Only that we don't subtract 2 for month 3; we subtract n-1 for month n. I've posted the query for flexible fiscal years.

Comment: Ok so i have to just do that modulo with 12. Thanks for the correct logic. 
Can we just replace first , second with actual month name ? I have also tried with monthname(date) but it is not allowing to do that.

Comment: datename(M,@startdate)

Comment: No, column names in SQL queries are fix. But this is something that you should not do in SQL, but in your application layer (app, Website) anyway. There you even see what language you must use for the user (my Windows is set to German for instance, which your DBMS is probably not).